# Есть ли в C# (.NET Core) сигма-типы? Нужен аналог std::variant из С++

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Есть ли в `C#` (`.NET Core`) сигма-типы? Меня интересует аналог [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) из `С++`. Если их нет, то как в `C#` принято решать задачи там, где в других языках используются сигма-типы (например передача и хранение объектов, которые могут иметь один из четырёх заранее заданных пользовательских типов)?

Comment: Смотрите [StructLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute) и [How to create a C/C++ union by using attributes (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/how-to-create-a-c-cpp-union-by-using-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите на dynamic

```
dynamic d1 = 7;
dynamic d2 = "a string";
dynamic d3 = System.DateTime.Today;
dynamic d4 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
```

Comment: Ага, прямо то, что нужно. Спасибо большое.